# Entity Framework Eager Loading Not Loading All Data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

Using Entity Framework 6, I'm trying to load an object graph with many children through eager loading.

Each Product has a collection of ProductDefinitions, each ProductDefinition has a collection of documents, and each document has a DocumentDetail.  For the purposes of the application, I need to load all the data at this point.

```
using (DatabaseEntities db = new DatabaseEntities())
{
    products = (from p in db.Products select p)
        .Include(p => p.ProductDefinition)
        .Include(p => p.ProductDefinition.Select(y=>y.ProductDocument))
        .Include(p => p.ProductDefinition.Select(y => y.ProductDocument.Select(o=>o.DocumentDetail)))                        
        .ToList();
}
```

Once products has been retrieved, I can use the Debugger Immediate Window to examine a particular product.

```
var productOfInterest = products.Single(p=>p.ProductIndex == "123456");
```

Looking through the Locals window, I can see that there are 129 documents associated with the product.
However, it is missing one record.

I can add another query that is related to the product of interest after the initial product query:

```
using (DatabaseEntities db = new DatabaseEntities())
{
    products = (from p in db.Products select p)
        .Include(p => p.ProductDefinition)
        .Include(p => p.ProductDefinition.Select(y=>y.ProductDocument))
        .Include(p => p.ProductDefinition.Select(y => y.ProductDocument.Select(o=>o.DocumentDetail)))                        
        .ToList();

     var docs = (from d in db.ProductDocument
                where d.ProductDefinitionID == 1092
                select d).ToList();
```

Then run the same Immediate Window command:

```
var productOfInterest = products.Single(p=>p.ProductIndex == "123456");
```

But now upon examining the Product through the Locals window, I find 130 documents.

I'm stumped as to why the eager loading didn't catch that document without the second query, and also why the second query changed the results at all.

EDIT:
Stepping through the code with both queries, once the variable products has been set, I can look and see the 129 items.  Stepping over the next query, the value in products updates to 130 items.

I didn't think that the items could be changed once the query has been executed by calling .ToList().  What am I mising?

Comment: The DbContext is caching the entities. You could even load them with individual queries and inside the DbContext the relationships are recognises and assigned accordingly.

Comment: @Peter Any clue as to why the results for the query would be different when comparing the .Include results vs after the specific query is run?  The database doesn't change, but the number of results does change once the second query is run (even though the results are never used).

Comment: Are you using virtual properties (as for lazy loading)?

Comment: Yes, but the .Includes should eagerly load them, right?  It's one of the child virtual properties that has the 129 count until a more specific query is done for that object, then it automatically updates to 130.

Comment: How does it behave, when you remove the virtual keyword? Lazy loading is a code smell anyway and I would get rid of it.